# Why does activator download dependencies when i run "activator test"

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

I could not find documentation, so I was wondering if anyone knew, why does activator download dependencies when i run "activator test". This seems odd to me, for example if I don't have internet connection, but I'd like to test my code how can I test my code, since it'll try to download dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You need the dependencies to test your code.

If you want to pre-download the dependencies, you can run `activator update` before running `test`.